# nativescript TNS Player giving an error while playing audio

Tags: audio, nativescript, angular5, angular2-nativescript

I am using nativescript to build that app. I want to use music player to play audio. I am using TNS Player https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio. Its working fine for some .mp3 files. But when file size more than 70-80 MB than its giving below error.

```
    TNSPlayer errorCallback,1
`{"player":{},"error":1,"extra":-1004}`
```

Function is

```
public async playAudio(filepath: string) {
const playerOptions: AudioPlayerOptions = {
  audioFile: filepath,
  loop: false,
  completeCallback: async () => {
    alert("Audio file complete.");
    await this._player.dispose();

    console.log("player disposed");
  },
  errorCallback: errorObject => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorObject));
  },
  infoCallback: args => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
  }
};
this._player.playFromUrl(playerOptions); }
```

Comment: That error is MEDIA_ERROR_IO
added in API level 17
int MEDIA_ERROR_IO
File or network related operation errors.

Constant Value: -1004 (0xfffffc14) --- I'm not sure what would cause it, maybe a drop in the network or an issue where the file is being loaded from.

Comment: Yes Brad, its always there when i am trying to access more than 70 MB file. if less than its working without error on android, in Iphone its taking 2 minutes buffer

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know more about it. Might want to search some android issues and see if you can find info that way, happy to help implement improvements to the plugin if possible.